# How to add data to a already existing json object without overwriting existing data

Tags: python, json

I have a json object in the form of a dictionary that i make outside of a function. I make a baseline for what the data inside the json object and its keys. What i am trying to do is to save the data i have collected in the function to the json object. I am very unsure on how i add that new data to the json data without overwriting any existing data already present in the json object.

Something i have tried to do is load the json object i am trying to update by doing:

```py
    import json
    data = json.loads(json_obj)
```

However, when i do this, it throws me an error when assigning new data to it.

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

This is the json object from before.

```json
    {
        "text": "test text",
        "created_at": "some date",
        "entity": "most_common_entity",
        "username": "someuser",
        "tweet_id": "coolid",
        "hashtags": "#coolndat"
    }
```

And the way i am attempting to add data to it is by doing:

```py
    json_obj["text"] = row["text"]
    json_obj["created_at"] = row["created_at"]
    json_obj["entity"] = most_common_entity
    json_obj["username"] = row["username"]
    json_obj["tweets_id"] = row["id"]
    json_obj["hashtags"] = row["hashtags"]
```

It would be amazing if anyone would be able to help my solve my problem.

The end goal would be for the json object to look something like this:

```json
    {
        {
            "text": "test text",
            "created_at": "some date",
            "entity": "most_common_entity",
            "username": "someuser",
            "tweet_id": "coolid",
            "hashtags": "#coolndat"
        },
        {
            "text": "Text two",
            "created_at": "12/5/3042",
            "entity": "ORG",
            "username": "cooluser3",
            "tweet_id": "nice",
            "hashtags": "#verysickhashtag"
        }
    }
```

Comment: None of samples you've provided is a valid JSON...

Comment: @OlvinRoght Sorry. Not very used to json.

Comment: json format is just a string written with some specific syntax. They might be confusing when using with Python because they LOOK LIKE Python dicts, but they are not python dicts. Python dicts can be dumped to json and json can be loaded to python dicts.

Example of variable that contains json:
`json_obj = '{"Hello": "World"}'`

Example of similar python dict
`python_dict = {"Hello": "World"}`

Comment: The code provided now is hopefully the correct json format. @Aidis

Comment: @RoaldAndreKvarv, still not... You want to make it list in last example *(`{` -> `[`)*

Comment: One more note. It is IMPOSSIBLE to have duplicate keys inside a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result that you expect to get is a set type, not a dict.
Here is an example how you could do that using list.

```py
In [7]: not_a_json_just_a_python_dict =     {
   ...:         "text": "test text",
   ...:         "created_at": "some date",
   ...:         "entity": "most_common_entity",
   ...:         "username": "someuser",
   ...:         "tweet_id": "coolid",
   ...:         "hashtags": "#coolndat"
   ...:     }

In [8]: list_of_dicts = [not_a_json_just_a_python_dict]

In [9]: list_of_dicts.append({
   ...:             "text": "test text",
   ...:             "created_at": "some date",
   ...:             "entity": "most_common_entity",
   ...:             "username": "someuser",
   ...:             "tweet_id": "coolid",
   ...:             "hashtags": "#coolndat"
   ...:         })

In [10]: list_of_dicts
Out[10]:
[{'text': 'test text',
  'created_at': 'some date',
  'entity': 'most_common_entity',
  'username': 'someuser',
  'tweet_id': 'coolid',
  'hashtags': '#coolndat'},
 {'text': 'test text',
  'created_at': 'some date',
  'entity': 'most_common_entity',
  'username': 'someuser',
  'tweet_id': 'coolid',
  'hashtags': '#coolndat'}]
```